# How to vectorise sampling from non-identically distributed Bernoulli random variables?

Tags: r, random, probability

Given a sequence of independent but not identically distributed Bernoulli trials with success probabilities given by a vector, e.g.:

```
x <- seq(0, 50, 0.1)
prob <- - x*(x - 50)/1000 # trial probabilities for trials 1 to 501
```

What is the most efficient way to obtain a random variate from each trial? I am assuming that vectorisation is the way to go.

I know of two functions that give Bernoulli random variates:

1. `rbernoulli` from the package `purr`, which does not accept a vector of success probabilities as an input. In this case it may be possible to wrap the function in an `apply` type operation.
2. `rbinom` with arguments `size = 1` gives Bernoulli random variates. It also accepts a vector of probabilities, so that:

   `rbinom(n = length(prob), size = 1, prob = prob)`

gives an output with the right length. However, I am not entirely sure that this is actually what I want. The bits in the helpfile `?rbinom` that seem relevant are:

> The length of the result is determined by n for rbinom, and is the
>   maximum of the lengths of the numerical arguments for the other
>   functions.
>
> The numerical arguments other than n are recycled to the length of the
>   result. Only the first elements of the logical arguments are used.

However, `n` is a parameter with no default, so I am not sure what the first sentence means. I presume the second sentence means that I get what I want, since only `size = 1` should be recycled. However [this thread](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Bernoulli-random-variable-with-different-probability-td2227587.html) seems to suggest that this method does not work.

This [blog post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/variable-probability-bernoulli-outcomes-fast-and-slow/) gives some other methods as well. One commentator mentions my suggested idea using `rbinom`.

Comment: You can iterate and simplify in purrr: `library(purrr); map_lgl(prob, ~rbernoulli(1, p = .x))`

Comment: That should be equivalent to (and slower than) just `as.logical(rbinom(length(prob), 1, prob))`, though. You can see that it works with something like `rbinom(500, 1, seq(0,1, len=500))`.

Comment: I can see that `rbinom` generates something that looks like what I want, but it makes me worried that elsewhere on the internet there seems to be plenty of references to other methods of doing this, and I am afraid the documentation of `rbinom` is not very clear to me.

Comment: `n` is how many numbers you get back. `size` is the number of trials, where success means 1 is added to the result, so if `size = 1`, you're running a single trial for each number returned. `prob` is the chance of success for each individual trial, and is vectorized (with recycling, if relevant). You've already got your answer; you just have to trust it. Or test it, if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to test that `rbinom` is vectorised for `prob`, taking advantage of the fact that the sum of N bernoulli random variables is a binomial random variable with denominator N:

```
x <- seq(0, 50, 0.1)
prob <- -x*(x - 50)/1000

n <- rbinom(prob, size=1000, prob)

par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
plot(prob ~ x)
plot(n ~ x)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't trust random strangers on the internet and do not understand documentation, maybe you can convince yourself by testing. Just set the random seed to get reproducible results:

```
x <- seq(0, 50, 0.1)
prob <- - x*(x - 50)/1000

#501 seperate draws of 1 random number
set.seed(42)
res1 <- sapply(prob, rbinom, n = 1, size = 1)

#501 "simultaneous" (vectorized) draws
set.seed(42)
res2 <- rbinom(501, 1, prob)

identical(res1, res2)
#[1] TRUE
```